# What is the size of a DIBSECTION?

Tags: winapi

I am looking to find the size of a device independent bitmap structure for use with GetObject in the windows API. I have an hBitmap. GetObject says that to get information about the hBitmap, I can either send a buffer with the size of a Bitmap structure or the size of a DIBSection. I don't know the exact sizes for a `BITMAP` and `DIBSECTION` struct are, can any one let me know what they are on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems?

Comment: Use `sizeof()` to get the size of either at runtime.

Comment: How do I do that? My math says 84 on 32-bit and 104 on 64-bit from reading the docs.

Comment: You don't need *your math*. You need to use the `sizeof()` operator.

Comment: @EdisonHua certainly, someone could just tell you the specific answer you are asking for, but that is not really going to help you long term. Many APIs take struct sizes as input. If you would explain WHY you can't use `sizeof` (ie, because you are using a language that doesn't have it available, which one?), then maybe someone can explain to you HOW to figure this out for yourself so that you don't have to ask again the next time you run into this same problem for another API.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I just needed the size of a DIBSECTION, sorry for any confusion, I don't know any better way to ask. Just. the. size. of. a. DiBsEcTioN.

Comment: I wasn't being condescending, and I didn't say you didn't need the size. I said you don't med the **math** if you use the `sizeof()` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I'm glad I reread the windows API documentation and looked though the pages detailing the structs. They happen to include everything needed to figure out the size of the struct, and I ended up [learning about pointer alignments through the sidebar](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/). I'm glad you all understand my question now. And finally I hope Chair Force Ken has a greater respect in my ability to do math because I believed in myself when he didn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I took out a piece of paper and added up everything myself.

A `DIBSECTION` contains 5 parts.

```
typedef struct tagDIBSECTION {
  BITMAP           dsBm;
  BITMAPINFOHEADER dsBmih;
  DWORD            dsBitfields[3];
  HANDLE           dshSection;
  DWORD            dsOffset;
} DIBSECTION, *LPDIBSECTION, *PDIBSECTION;
```

So let's start with `BITMAP`.

```
typedef struct tagBITMAP {
  LONG   bmType;
  LONG   bmWidth;
  LONG   bmHeight;
  LONG   bmWidthBytes;
  WORD   bmPlanes;
  WORD   bmBitsPixel;
  LPVOID bmBits;
} BITMAP, *PBITMAP, *NPBITMAP, *LPBITMAP;
```

A `LONG` is just an `int` which is 4 bytes. A `WORD` is a `unsigned short` which is 2 bytes. And `LPVOID` is a `ptr`.

`4+4+4+4+2+2` = `20`. But wait, a struct has to be aligned properly. So we need to test divisibility by `8` on 64-bit systems. 20 is not divisible by 8, so we add 4 bytes of padding to get `24`. Adding the `ptr` gives us `32`.

The size of the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is 40 bytes. It's divisible by 8, so nothing fancy needed. We're at `72` now.

Back to the `DIBSECTION`. There's an array of `DWORD`s. And each `DWORD` is an `unsigned int`. Adding 12 to 72 gives us `84`.

Now there's a `handle`. A handle is basically a pointer, whose value can be 4 or 8 depending on 32 or 64 bit. Time to check if `84` is divisible by 8. It's not so we add 4 bytes of padding to get `88`. Then add the pointer to get `96`.

Finally there's the last `DWORD` and the total reaches `100` on a 64-bit system.

But what about `sizeof()`?????? Can't you just do `sizeof(DIBSECTION)`? After all magic numbers = bad. Ken White said in the comments that I didn't need to do any math. I disagree with this. First, as a programmer, it's essential to understand what is happening and why. Nothing could be more elementary than memory on a computer. Second, I only tagged the post as `winapi`. For the people reading this, if you scroll down on the `GetObject` page, the function is exported on `Gdi32.dll`. Any windows program has access to `Gdi32.dll`. Not every windows program has access to `sizeof()`. Third, it may be important for people who need to know the math to have the steps shown. Not everyone programs in a high level language. It might even be a question on an exam.

Perhaps the real question is if a struct of size 100 gets padded to 104 when memory is being granted on a 64-bit system.

Comment: your math logic on `BITMAP` is a little misleading, but your end result is correct. Struct alignment is more than just making sure the overall size of the struct is evenly divisible. You also have to make sure that every data member starts at an offset that is divisible by its own alignment. That can introduce padding in between data members, not just at the end of the struct. That is why you had to add bytes before the `LPVOID`. And this can especially be true when structs hold other structs.

Comment: The first value of a bitmap struct is 40. It is always 40 because that is the predetermined size of the struct. Given that 40 is divisible by the size of a pointer (8 and 4) there are no offsets to compute.

Comment: it is not the alignment of a pointer that is used. The Win32 API uses a qword (8 byte) alignment on both 32-bit and 64-bit ([see this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090422-00/?p=18493)). It just happens that a 64-bit pointer is *also* 8 bytes.

Comment: So hypothetically, a 128-bit value would be stored at the 8 byte alignment as well. Does this have any impact on any current structs? Anything I should watch out for?

Comment: The claim here that `sizeof` is not available in all languages that can consume the Win32 API is incorrect. Either the `sizeof` operator *or an equivalent functionality* is available in any case where you have Win32 API bindings, and it should always be preferred over hardcoding sizes. If you want to calculate the size as an instructional exercise, then that's fine, but you should never hard-code this information into your source code, regardless of which language you are writing in. And this would be a *terrible* exam question. I write in assembly (not high-level), and I don't hardcode sizes.

Comment: The claim is that languages that can execute DLL calls directly, or indirectly via an associated COM scripting object do not have access to the Win32 API headers. In any case, this question does have practical applications, for example, if the creation of a DIBSection were to be communicated via a packet from a remote OS, how large should the size of the packet be? Any assumption that the remote OS even runs on Windows may be invalid. Questions such as this fall under the scope of cybersecurity, reverse engineering, and low-level design.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any math manually.  Simply declare a `DIBSECTION` variable, and then pass a pointer to it to `GetObject()` along with `sizeof()` as the size of that variable, eg:

```
DIBSECTION dib;
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(dib), &dib);
```

Comment: Notice I never specified any language, just winapi? Bold to assume I have the sizeof() operator available, as well as the header files.

Comment: @EdisonHua the Win32 API is a C-based API, so *IT* makes certain assumptions about developers' environments. And most languages have a way to query the size of a type. But if you really want better help, then you should mention the actual language you are using

Comment: The Win32 API is exported in a series of DLLs. In fact any program that runs on windows has access to GDI32.dll. Yes. Any program.

Comment: @EdisonHua any *C-compatible* language, that is. There are languages that can't access Win32 DLLs and/or various functions of the API due to language restrictions